# What are .hint files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, deprecated

While writing a program in C++ I came across a piece of code:

```
#define _DEPRE_ [[deprecated("This is deprecated")]]
```

and used it above a function definition to show that the function is deprecated. But Intellisense showed
to rectify the error by adding it into another file having an extension of .hint.Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A hint file contains macros that would otherwise cause regions of code
>   to be skipped by the C++ Browsing Database Parser. When you open a
>   Visual Studio C++ project, the parser analyzes the code in each source
>   file in the project and builds a database with information about every
>   identifier. The IDE uses that information to support code browsing
>   features.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Hint Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/hint-files?view=vs-2019)